# Flare animation not showing up when running app

Tags: flutter, dart, flare

I am trying to run the below animation, however, it is not showing up on the screen when i run the app. I am using the mediaquery instead of hard coded numbers for the coordinates so that the animation renders in the same place regardless of screen size.

Is there something wrong with the way i am implementing this?

```
       SizedBox(
          child: FlareActor(
            "assets/animations/finding-pizza.flr",
            alignment: Alignment(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
              MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,),
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
            animation: _animationName,
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: did you asign a value to this _animationName,

Comment: yes, the animation is there but it is not showing up i think because of the coordinates i am specifying through the mediaquery - i've been trying to change these but to no avail

Comment: for testing try animation:"myanimation" and then see whether it works.

Comment: Any update on this?